# Issue in performance when load testing using azure application gateway

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I'm facing a big difference in load testing results when running the load testing using JMeter to access the system using the Azure application gateway vs access the backing server directly.

My Current Setup is:
+ Azure Application Gateway with SSL Offloading
+ WAF Enabled
+ OWASP 3.0 Rule set enabled with "no" excluded or added rules

Below are my trials:

- All pointers through the internet point to an issue in firewall and rule set "like using OWASP 3.0 rule set for example", while this seems to enhances the situation, but there is still a big difference too.
- Increasing SKU sizes and instance count is indifferent too, we tried to increase SKU to large and instance count up to 30, but no difference in performance
- Disabling the WAF provides better load testing numbers, but not the same as accessing the backend server directly.

Noting that we perform the load testing from a jump box VM within the same virtual network.

What are the steps needed to get the same results using the application gateway as accessing the backing server directly

Comment: Can you provide more information on your setup? Are you using end to end SSL? Is WAF enabled? Does disabling WAF producing any improvements? Are there any WAF logs collected post test?

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: Thanks, i have updated the issue description with more details.

Comment: Application Gateway is a Reverse Proxy which means, a new connection is created to the backend resource. What is the backend resource of Application Gateway ? Is it a VM or web App? Is the resource is in the same region as that of Application Gateway? Are you seeing improvements when you try from the Jump Box?

Comment: yes, all are in the same region and virtual network, the backend is a VM containing apache tomcat. and all my testing is from the jumpbox (which is inside the same virtual network, and region accordingly). I never tested from outside the environment.

Comment: In the access logs there is a column where you can find the latency between Application Gateway and the Backend servers. I will be interested to checking that.